# Patriot Blast SSD - 100°C?

Tags: ssd, temperature

So, it appears my Disks utility on Ubuntu 15.10 thinks my SSD is running at a constant 100°C temperature. And S.M.A.R.T. data seems to be stuck at 30 on temperature, since it doesn't seem to change, ever.
I've heard many SSDs don't have temperature sensors at all, but why would Ubuntu report it at all? I highly suspect the SSD I literally bought today isn't running at that high a temperature, and that it's a false positive of sorts, but I'd like to know more. Is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's 100°C, that's high enough that it's certainly not accurate.

The likely explanation is that it's a software bug, due in part to the drive being so new that it's unlikely this software utility had been tested with it.

You could try installing the package hddtemp and using the hddtemp tool to check the drive temperature.  There's a chance it'll say the same thing, but maybe not.

An SSD is usually not something you'd normally need to worry about getting too hot - they don't usually require active cooling and don't have moving parts.  As long as you have working ventilation/fans in your case it should be fine.  Unless you have some other reason to be concerned, you probably don't need a working temperature indicator on your SSD.

Comment: I tried `hddtemp` on my /dev/sda 240GB SSD - KINGSTON SHSS37A240G (SAFM00.U) and it reports 40C however `disks` still reports 100C. On my /dev/sdc 128GB mSata SSD - Kingfast F9m temperature matches at 40C and on my /dev/sdc 500 GB HDD - ST9500423AS temperatures match at 53C. In my case at least installing hddtemp was not a fix for disks. That said there are no linux distros installed on /dev/sda which is pretty much unused except for grub booting..